# Bug with edit history on documentation topic involving removal/moving in the past

Tags: bug, documentation

The edit history for [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/1950/record-syntax) is [an "Oops" page](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/haskell/revisions/1950).

When the edit history is accessed from [the individual example in quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/1950/record-syntax/13072/recordwildcards#t=20160729174800427191), [it works OK](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/revisions/1950?exampleId=13072).

Comment: More clearly, the edit history for Haskell's Remarks section is an oops page.

Comment: @Laurel no, it belongs to the whole topic, not just its Remarks section. Same thing happens when clicking on ["edited'](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/revisions/1950), [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/topics?page=2&tab=popular).

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I'm reporting a bug. @VeniVidiVici

Comment: Look, ma, a downvote as a reward for giving a damn and reporting a bug! How wonderful!